# How to set form field values in bulk using Coded UI Tests in C# without knowing HTML tag type ahead of time

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, specflow

I'm using SpecFlow in combination with Coded UI Tests, and I have a need to set values on multiple form fields where I know the Id of the HTML tag, but I don't necessarily know the underlying `System.Type` that corresponds to that HTML tag in Coded UI Tests.

Basically, I want to assign values to form fields using Coded UI Tests in a generic way.

Example SpecFlow step:

```
When I fill in the "Hours of Operation Information" table with the following values:
    | Shift    | From    | To      |
    | DAY ONLY | 12:30AM | 12:00AM |
    | DAY ONLY | 12:30AM | 12:00AM |
    | DAY ONLY | 12:30AM | 12:00AM |
    | DAY ONLY | 12:30AM | 12:00AM |
    | DAY ONLY | 12:30AM | 12:00AM |
    | DAY ONLY | 12:30AM | 12:00AM |
    | DAY ONLY | 12:30AM | 12:00AM |
```

The "Shift", "From" and "To" column headings get mapped to an HTML tag Id, which I will omit for brevity, and because this mapping works.

The step definition:

```
[When(@"I fill in the ""(.*)"" table with the following values:")]
public void WhenIFillInTheTableWithTheFollowingValues(string tableName, Table table)
{
    HtmlTable grid = GetGrid(tableName);
    HtmlControl control = null;
    TableRow row = null;
    string id;

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        row = table.Rows[i];

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> column in row)
        {
            id = String.Format(FormMap.GetFieldName(tableName, column.Key), i);
            control = new HtmlControl(grid);
            control.SearchProperties[HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id] = id;
            Assert.IsTrue(control.Exists, "Form field '{0}' does not exist in row {1} of the '{2}' grid (id={3}).", column.Key, i, tableName, id);

            // How do I set the form field value?
        }
    }
}
```

I created a helper method that takes an `HtmlControl` object and a value, then looks at the HTML tag name. It then attempts to cast it to the appropriate class so I can interact with it.

```
public void SetFormFieldValue(HtmlControl control, object value)
{
    string controlValue = value == null ? null : value.ToString();
    string tagName = control.TagName.ToLower();
    string fieldType = null;

    switch (tagName)
    {
        case "select":
            ((HtmlComboBox)control).SelectedItem = controlValue;
            break;
        case "input":
            fieldType = control.GetProperty(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Type).ToString().ToLower();

            switch (fieldType)
            {
                case "text":
                case "password":
                    ((HtmlEdit)control).Text = controlValue;
                    break;
                case "checkbox":
                    ((HtmlCheckBox)control).Checked = controlValue.ToLower() == "checked";
                    break;
                case "radio":
                    ((HtmlRadioButton)control).Selected = controlValue.ToLower() == "checked";
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Cannot set value on {0}[type={1}]", tagName, fieldType));
            }

            break;
        case "textarea":
            ((HtmlTextArea)control).Text = controlValue;
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Cannot set value on {0} tag.", tagName));
    }
}
```

In this particular scenario, I'm trying to set values on `<select>` boxes. I am getting the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlControl' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlComboBox'.

**Question:**

How can I set values on form fields in bulk using Coded UI Tests without knowing the HTML tag type ahead of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should know better than to ask a question, because I always end up finding the answer just after I ask it.

There is a method called [UITestControl.CopyFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.copyfrom.aspx) which takes any `UITestControl` object and copies it to the source object:

```
public void SetFormFieldValue(HtmlControl control, object value)
{
    string controlValue = value == null ? null : value.ToString();
    string tagName = control.TagName.ToLower();
    string fieldType = null;

    switch (tagName)
    {
        case "select":
            // The concrete Coded UI Test class I want to interact with
            HtmlComboBox select = new HtmlComboBox();
            // Make the `select` object reference the same element as `control`
            select.CopyFrom(control);
            // Set the value on the dropdown list
            select.SelectedItem = controlValue;
            break;
        case "textarea":
            HtmlTextArea textarea = new HtmlTextArea();
            textarea.CopyFrom(control);
            textarea.Text = controlValue;
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```